# Regex containing at-least 3 of the following [0-9], [a-z], [A-Z] or special characters (except $)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regex-negation

I need a regular expression for validating an input field in HTML. The pattern should contain at least three of the followings:

1. Number [0-9]
2. Uppercase alphabets [A-Z]
3. Lowercase alphabets[a-z]
4. Special characters (except $)
5. and the minimum length is 6.

Valid Input String:

> 1. AAss11
> 2. AA11@@
> 3. aa11@@
> 4. AAss@@

Invalid Input String:

> 1. AAAAAA
> 2. AA11111
> 3. aa111111
> 4. AA@@@@@@
> 5. AAss11$
> 6. 1111111
> 7. @@@@@@
> 8. $1Asssss
> 9. AAss11@$

I have written this regex:

```
    ^(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[^$])|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.
[!#%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~])[^$])|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.
[!#%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~])[^$])|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.
[!#%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~])[^$])).{6,16}$
```

Comment: Don't. Quite aside from "password rules" just making users use less secure passwords (eg. `Password1!`) to meet your arbitrary requirements... By using a single regex you have no way of telling the user what is wrong with their input. Instead, test for the presence of each thing you want, and inform the user exactly what they're missing.

Comment: Here's a [demonstration](https://howsecureismypassword.net/) of the fallacy in using password rules. The moral of the story is memorable phrases are far more difficult to crack and much easier to remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do all the iterations (3 of 4). If ECMAScript new comes out, and
it supports conditionals `(?(cond)yes|no)` this is greatly simplified.

Here it is, out-of-order :

```
^(?:(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!"#%&'()*,\-./:;?@[\]_{}])|(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!"#%&'()*,\-./:;?@[\]_{}])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!"#%&'()*,\-./:;?@[\]_{}]))[0-9a-zA-Z!"#%&'()*,\-./:;?@[\]_{}]{6,16}$
```

Expanded view

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      (?= .* [0-9] )
      (?= .* [a-z] )
      (?= .* [A-Z] )
      #(?= .*[!"#%&'()*,\-./:;?@[\]_{}] )

   |  
      (?= .* [0-9] )
      (?= .* [a-z] )
      #(?= .*[A-Z] )
      (?= .* [!"#%&'()*,\-./:;?@[\]_{}] )

   |  
      (?= .* [0-9] )
      #(?= .*[a-z] )
      (?= .* [A-Z] )
      (?= .* [!"#%&'()*,\-./:;?@[\]_{}] )

   |  
      #(?= .*[0-9] )
      (?= .* [a-z] )
      (?= .* [A-Z] )
      (?= .* [!"#%&'()*,\-./:;?@[\]_{}] )

 )
 [0-9a-zA-Z!"#%&'()*,\-./:;?@[\]_{}]{6,16} 
 $
```

JS sample

```js
var RxPwd = new RegExp("^(?:(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!\"#%&'()*,\\-./:;?@[\\]_{}])|(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!\"#%&'()*,\\-./:;?@[\\]_{}])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!\"#%&'()*,\\-./:;?@[\\]_{}]))[0-9a-zA-Z!\"#%&'()*,\\-./:;?@[\\]_{}]{6,16}$", "mg");

var strPwdTest = 
// Should pass
"AAss11\n"  +
"AA11@@\n"  +
"aa11@@\n"  +
"AAss@@\n"  +
// Should fail
"AAAAAA\n"  +
"AA11111\n"  +
"aa111111\n"  +
"AA@@@@@@\n"  +
"AAss11$\n"  +
"1111111\n"  +
"@@@@@@\n"  +
"$1Asssss\n"  +
"AAss11@$\n";

var match;

while ( match = RxPwd.exec( strPwdTest ) )
{
    console.log( match[0], "\t ..Passed" );
}
```